# How to display shortTime in 12/24 hour format depending on user's settings

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a sub that displays a user's last login time.  Currently it takes the time that user last logged in, converts it to local time and will display in general short time.  This is done by:

```
subItem("Last_Login").Text = login.ToString("g", 
                                            DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

and it correctly displays the short form of the date and time (in 24 hour format) as the user's last login time.

I am looking to change this so the time is displayed however the user using the application has their time formatted.

For example if the time is displayed as `6/18/2014 3:02 PM` it will display that in the form. If my time is set to 24-hour clock format, the user would see the time as `6/18/2014 13:02`

I've tried:
`subItem("Last_Login").Text = login.ToString()` 
and this works.  However it displays the longTimePattern.  But when I add the `"g"` and `"t"` seem to go off of the user's region setting, not their clock setting.

I also tried adding a new `DateTimeFormatInfo` object and using `dtFormat.ShortTimePattern` as defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but again - no luck.

In closing, I am currently getting `6/18/2014 3:14:00 PM` as the last login time, but I need to get `6/18/2014 3:14 PM` (what the clock on the taskbar actually shows).  Alternatively, if my clock was set to a 24-hour format instead of 12, I'd need to see `6/18/2014 13:14` instead of `6/18/2014 13:14:00`.

How can this be done?

Edit: when debugging, I will check the immediate window to see what my ShortTimePattern is and it always comes up as `h:mm tt` never `H:mm` even when my clock is set to 24-hour format.  That seems to be the main issue here.

[image: My regional time settings which should display 24-hour clock short time]
[image: Still getting 12-hour short time]

Comment: I deleted my answer because it is no longer useful after your edit. Can you check to see whether you also have this problem in a brand new project? It's possible that something else in your project is messing with the settings, but I don't think there's enough information in your question to be more specific about that.

Comment: I think you're right.  I think it's more a permissions issue with the online environment I am using because a local project does what I am trying to do just fine.  I can't delete this question because Malky has an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

The login details is coming from here `subItem("Last_Login").Text` correct?

You can pass it on to a Date variable, and from there convert int's format into the one you specified

```
             dim x as Date = subItem("Last_Login").Text
             msgbox(x.tostring("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"))
```